# Inner join same table syntax error

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to run an inner join between this same table. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
(SELECT user_key, bill_number, MAX(payment_date) AS payment_date 
 FROM billpayment) bpt 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM billpayment) bp
   ON bp.user_key=bpt.user_key 
   AND bp.bill_number=bpt.bill_number 
   AND bp.payment_date=bpt.payment_date 
 GROUP BY user_key, bill_number;
```

It says that the sql command is not properly ended at the parenthesis in 'billpayment)'

Comment: mysql or Oracle? Please only tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the beginning and after `FROM billpayment`

Comment: What are you trying to acheive here? Select from this table where it exists in the same table? Because that's what this query does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     user_key, 
     bill_number, 
     MAX(payment_date) AS payment_date 
    FROM billpayment bpt 
    INNER JOIN billpayment bp 
    ON bp.user_key=bpt.user_key 
    AND bp.bill_number=bpt.bill_number AND bp.payment_date=bpt.payment_date 
    GROUP BY 
     user_key, bill_number

;
```

Comment: would it help to include a JOIN ON condition like `bp.payment_date <> bpt.payment_date`, so as to avoid joining one record in both the left and right tables, or would that possibly exclude critical combinations?

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle Try this:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT user_key, bill_number, MAX (payment_date) AS payment_date FROM billpayment) bpt
         INNER JOIN billpayment bp
            ON bp.user_key = bpt.user_key AND bp.bill_number = bpt.bill_number AND bp.payment_date = bpt.payment_date
    GROUP BY user_key, bill_number;
```

Can't test it without the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using analytic functions?

```
select bp.*,
       max(bp.paymentdate) over (partition by user_key, bill_number) as max_payment_date
from billpayment
```

If you want the fields on the max payment date:

```
select bp.*
from (select bp.*,
             max(bp.paymentdate) over (partition by user_key, bill_number) as max_paymentdate
      from billpayment
     ) bp
where paymentdate = max_paymentdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

On mySQL, you can try something like:

```
 SELECT bpt.user_key, bpt.bill_number, MAX(bpt.payment_date) AS payment_date 
 FROM billpayment bpt 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM billpayment) bp
   ON bp.user_key=bpt.user_key 
   AND bp.bill_number=bpt.bill_number 
   AND bp.payment_date=bpt.payment_date 
 GROUP BY bpt.user_key, bpt.bill_number;
```